# Admob: Deactivation of advertising in my application linked to Site behavior: navigation

Tags: android, react-native, admob, adsense

For several weeks the advertising has been destructive in my application but until now I have not been able to understand the cause.
I would like you to help me find the cause or give me information on how to contact Admob support regarding this problem.
Here is the link to my application: https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.zinnoussou.couturehomme

[image: This is the screenshot of the problem details]
[image: Screenshot 1: This is one of the screenshots of the screens where the problem resides according to Admob]
[image: Screenshot 2: This is one of the screenshots of the screens where the problem resides according to Admob]
[image: Screenshot 3: This is one of the screenshots of the screens where the problem resides according to Admob]
[image: Screenshot 4: This is one of the screenshots of the screens where the problem resides according to Admob]

Initially I thought that these were the intertitial advertisements or the ads when opening the application. I made changes to reduce the loading time between each ad but nothing. Currently I have completely deactivated advertising in the app but the problem is still not resolved.